# How to change default volume mount in VS Code Remote Container?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

How to change the default volume mount for the folder opened in the container? I have tried in my `Dockerfile`:

```
RUN mkdir /root/myproject
WORKDIR /root/myproject
```

As well as my `.devcontainer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "My Project",
    "dockerFile": "Dockerfile",
    "workspaceFolder": "/root/myproject",
}
```

But the folder is still being mounted on `/workspaces/myproject` within the container.

Comment: Note that `RUN mkdir /root/myproject` is unnecessary, because `WORKDIR` automatically creates the dir anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Update**

The upcoming vscode-container release should support using `workspaceFolder` as you show. See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/101) for details.

---

If you are using an older version of the remote extensions, it is not possible to do this when using a single dockerfile, but you can do this using the `workspaceFolder` setting for a [docker-compose dev container](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers#_extending-your-docker-compose-file-for-development):

`.devcontainer/devcontainer.json`:

```
{
    "name": "My Project",
    "dockerComposeFile": "docker-compose.yml",
    "service": "my-service-name",
    "workspaceFolder": "/customPath"
}
```

`.devcontainer/docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3'
services:
  my-service-name:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - ..:/customPath
    command: sleep infinity
```

You can change `customPath` to whatever path you would like the workspace to be mounted to. Also, make sure to add the `command: sleep infinity` for containers would automatically shutdown when started