# Mounting local directory to home directory in container

Tags: vscode-remote

I had hoped that using `"workspaceFolder": "/home/jovyan",` in `devcontainer.json` would do the the trick but that doesn't seem to do anything when using an existing image/container. The below works on macOS but is tied to username on the host system and would not work on Windows.

Is there some variable that vscode uses that would allow the local directory to be mounted to the home directory in the container?

```
"runArgs": [
    "-v",
    "/Users/a_user/project_1:/home/jovyan",
]
```

EDIT:

Just noticed [How to change default volume mount?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55970168/how-to-change-default-volume-mount?rq=1) and feature request https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/101. Also https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release/issues/171

Answer (score 0):

Update: The local workspace folder is available as `${localWorkspaceFolder}` ([documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/containers-advanced#_changing-the-default-source-code-mount)).

Comment: The home folder in the container is known (e.g., `/home/jovyan'). However, the folder to mount (e.g.,, `/Users/a_user/project_1`) will vary depending on where code/data is stored on a user's computer and on the OS. The `docker run` command that vscode generates does know the directory to mount and I would like to access that same information to mount to `/home/jovyan` (or `home/jovyan/project_1`) rather than `/workspace/project_1`

Comment: @christof-marti, It seems to me that `containerWorkspaceFolder` reflects `workspaceFolder` (for use e.g in `mount` directive in `devcontainer.json`). Is there something similar now (or in the near future) that would work the same for `remoteUser` (i.e sort of `containerRemoteUser` that would allow mount according to `remoteUser` value).

Comment: @nvidot That is not planned at the moment. The main value would be to avoid duplication as opposed to, e.g., ${localWorkspaceFolder} which is unknown otherwise.